# Test if a number is within 2 of a multiple of 10

Tags: java, integer

I have solved this exercise, but it looks really redundant. Is there a built-in function in Java or a cleaner way to caluclate mod of a value + deviation without multiple OR statements? If I had to calculate this for a deviation of 5, this would then require a lot of repetition.

> Given a non-negative number "num", return true if num is within 2 of a multiple of 10. Note: (a % b) is the remainder of dividing a by b, so (7 % 5) is 2.

```java
    public boolean nearTen(int num) {
        return isMod10(num) || isMod10(num - 1) || isMod10(num + 1) || isMod10(num - 2) || isMod10(num + 2);
    }

    private boolean isMod10(int num) {
        return num % 10 == 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should read about congruent integers and [modular arithmic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_relation). The distance of a number to a *base* is the minimum distance of its *congruent* value and its *inverted congruent* value.

```
 public boolean nearBase(int num, int base, int deviation) {

        // ..TODO check guards, normalize input or throw exceptions 
        // - base and deviation are expected strict positive integers
        // - deviation is expected smaller than base
        // - num is expected a positive integer

        var congruent = num % base;
        var inverted = base - congruent;
        var distance = Math.min(congruent, inverted);
        return distance <= deviation;
    }

 // your method rewritten ->
 public boolean nearTen(int num) {
        return nearBase(num, 10, 2);
    }
```

Comment: Okay, thanks! I had this topic in introductory algebra but did not think about it at all.

Answer (score 3):

Let's consider the results of numbers around 10 as an example :

> ```
> 7 % 10 = 7
> 8 % 10 = 8
> 9 % 10 = 9
> 10 % 10 = 0
> 11 % 10 = 1
> 12 % 10 = 2
> 13 % 10 = 3
> ```

We know that 8 to 12 should be included.

For 10 to 12 it's easy, we just need to check if their modulo is smaller than 2.

```
public boolean nearTen(int num) {
    int modulo = num % 10;
    return modulo <= 2;
}
```

For 8 and 9, if we look at the above results, we can see that the difference between their modulo and the original number will give us a number under 2. So we'll add that to the algorithm:

```
public boolean nearTen(int num) {
    int modulo = num % 10;
    return modulo <= 2 || num - modulo <= 2;
}
```

With that, we covered all cases. When facing a problem like this one, don't be afraid to write down the results and try to find a match.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of your individual checks of the deviations in the range `-2 .. 2`, you could check the range as such. With a lower bound check and an upper bound check. Although `-2 .. 2` doesn't play well because `% 10` splits it into `8 .. 9` and `0 .. 2`. Shifting by 2 gives you the simpler range `0 .. 4`, which `% 10` leaves intact, and where we get the lower bound for free and only have to check the upper bound:

```
    public boolean nearTen(int num) {
        return (num + 2) % 10 <= 4;
    }
```

Btw, about yours you say *"If I had to calculate this for a deviation of 5, this would then require a lot of repetition"*, which isn't true. *Every* integer is within 5 of a multiple of 10, so you wouldn't need *any* checks for that. Anyway, for a generalization, you could do this:

```
    public boolean nearTen(int num, maxDeviation) {
        return (num + maxDeviation) % 10 <= 2 * maxDeviation;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to @[RoastedPotatoe](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/202056/roastedpotatoe)'s answer above; I now understand that we want to consider only those numbers which are in the range \$((10-2)\%10)\$ to \$((10+2)\%10)\$. For example \$(8\%10)\$ to \$(12\%10)\$.

This means our use cases to be passed are:

- \$(8\%10=8)\$,
- \$(9\%10=9)\$,
- \$(10\%10=0)\$,
- \$(11\%10=1)\$, and
- \$(12\%10=2)\$.

From here I know I can just say:

- if the remainder comes out to be 8 or 9 return true. Otherwise,
- if the remainder to be between 0 and 2 return true. Otherwise,
- return false.

```
public boolean nearTen(int num){
    if((num%10==8 || num%10==9) || (num%10 >= 0  && num%10 <= 2)) return true;
    else return false;
}
```